# Aws SAM lambda cannot assume role to use dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have deployed a SAM template with lambda to use an **existing dynamo database**. The template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
  Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
     
  Parameters:
    myTable: 
      Description: table ARN 
      Type: String
  
  Resources:
    createData:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        CodeUri: src/myApp
        Handler: com.xxx.App::handleRequest
        Runtime: java11
        Architectures:
          - x86_64
        MemorySize: 512
        Environment:
          Variables:
            PARAM1: VALUE
            JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
        Events:
          apiPut:
            Type: Api
            Properties:
              Path: /myapp
              Method: put
        Policies:
          - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
              TableName: !Ref myTable
```

When I deploy de app, i insert the param myTable ARN: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:table/TABLE_NAME. When I call the api, i have an error because lambda dont have permissions to putItem in dynamoDB:

> User:
> arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/APP_ROLE/LAMBDA_APP
> is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource:
> arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXX:table/TABLE_NAME because no
> identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action

Why?

Comment: `tableName` should be be table name, not its ARN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply provide only the `TableName` not the entire `ARN` for `DynamoDBCrudPolicy`

https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/docs/policy_templates.rst